# jQuery - Updating and saving changes using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a function that Creates new items and allows you to Delete, Update and Save the inputs on these items using `localStorage`

However, if I have more than one item and then update and save the changes, those changes are applied over all items.

The problem is encountered at the `$(".save").click(function()` but I'm not sure I have set up my `.items` with a proper array.

Since I use `localStorage` the working code can be found in the pen below:

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/NoBQKV

```
window.localStorage.clear();
//create localStorage item
if (!localStorage.getItem("_storage")) {
  localStorage.setItem("_storage", "");
}
//set data to localStorage function
function saveData() {
  localStorage.setItem("_storage", $("#content").html());
}
// Open the create dialgoue:
$(".add").on("click", function() {
  $(".create").toggle();
});
//Save the entered inputs and post the item:
$(".post").click(function() {
  var id = $(".createtext").val();
  var createtitle = $(".createtitle").val();
  var item = "";
  if (id[0]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
      item += "<div>" + id[i] + "</div>";
    }
  } else {
    item = "<div>Click update to add a card</div>";
  }
  $("#content").append(
    '<div class="item">' +
      '<div class="title">' +
      createtitle +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='text'>" +
      id +
      "</div>" +
      '<button class="delete">Delete</button>' +
      '<button class="update">Update</button>' +
      "</div>"
  );
  $(".createtitle").val("");
  $(".createtext").val("");
  $(".create").toggle();
  saveData();
});
//Close out of creating a new item
$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".createtitle").val("");
  $(".createtext").val("");
  $(".create").toggle();
});
//Get inputs and open edit window to update the items:
$("#content").on("click", ".update", function() {
  var item = $(this).closest(".item");
  $(".updatetext").val(
    $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .find(".text")
      .text()
  );
  $(".updatetitle").val(
    $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .find(".title")
      .text()
  );
  $(".edit").toggle();
});
//Save changes and update the items (error:changes all items when clicked):
$(".save").click(function() {
  var id = $(".updatetext").val();
  var title = $(".updatetitle").val();
  var item = "";
  if (id[0]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
      item += "<div>" + id[i] + "</div>";
    }
  } else {
    item = "<p>Click edit to add a card</p>";
  }
  $(".item").each(function() {
    $(this).html(
      '<div class="title">' +
        title +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='text'>" +
        id +
        "</div>" +
        '<button class="delete">Deleted(2)</button>' +
        '<button class="update">Updated(2)</button>'
    );
  });
  $(".updatetext").val("");
  $(".updatetitle").val("");
  $(".edit").toggle();
  saveData();
});
//Discard any of these changes:
$(".discard").click(function() {
  $(".updatetext").val("");
  $(".updatetitle").val("");
  $(".edit").toggle();
});
//Delete an item:
$("#content").on("click", ".delete", function() {
  $(this)
    .closest(".item")
    .remove();
  saveData();
});
$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("_storage")) {
    $("#content").html(localStorage.getItem("_storage"));
  }
});
```

Comment: You literally update all items with this code: `$(".item").each(function() {` (line 78). You need to acknowledge what element exactly you are editing. Do you need help with that?

Comment: Yes I need a solution. I thought `each` was handling the identifier.

Comment: No, it means it'll go over each suitable element. You keep track of element on edit here on line 54: `var item = $(this).closest(".item");`. But you need to make that info accessible in `update` function. Easiest (but not the best) way to do that - take that variable to upper level, and then do `item.html(...)` in `update` function. Does it make sense?

Comment: Are you able to work a solution in the codepen?

Comment: Check this out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzXaoV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point is, you call `.each()` in your update callback.

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
    $(this).html(
      '<div class="title"> ....'
    );
  });
```

This literally means "Find **all** DOM elements with `item` class and replace their contents with given html.

But you need to replace contents of the one specific element, on which `Update` button was clicked. To do so, you need to persist that element somehow.

One of the ways to do that with minimum changes to your code - introduce a variable in a scope available for both `update` and `save` functions. But in your case it would be a global variable, and those are not generally a good idea.

So I'd suggest to wrap all your code into a function (like `$(function() {});`.
Then you can introduce a local variable:

```js
$(function () {
  // define it
  var $selectedItem;

  // assign a value in the update click callback
  $('#content').on('click', '.update', function () {
    $selectedItem = $(this).closest('.item');
    // ...
  });

  // read the value in the save click callback
  $('.save').click(function () {
    // ...
    $selectedItem.html('...');
    // ...
  });
});
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzXaoV